# MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I built this app with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408550/structure-of-a-synchronous-application-in-node-js-and-mongodb/49409296?noredirect=1#comment85825494_49409296) I did previously.

**app.js**:

```
var mongolib = require('./middlewares/db.js');
var downloaderCoverageWho = require('./routers/downloaderCoverageWho.js');
var downloaderCoverageIta = require('./routers/downloaderCoverageIta.js');

const start = async function() {
    const conn = await mongolib.connectToMongoDb();
    const coverages = await mongolib.createACollection('coverages');
    const isPageHasUpdates = true; 
    if(isPageHasUpdates) {
        await downloadCoverageIta();
        await downloadCoverageWho();
    }
    await mongolib.closeConnection();
    await console.log('d3.js creation...');
    return 'FINISH';
}
start()
.then(res => console.log(res)) 
.catch(err => console.log(err)); 

async function downloadCoverageWho() {
    await downloaderCoverageWho.download();
    console.log('Finish');
}
async function downloadCoverageIta() {
    await downloaderCoverageIta.download();
    console.log('Finish');
}
```

**db.js**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const dbName = 'db';
var collCovName = 'coverages';
var collCov;
let myClient;
let myConn;

var methods = {};

methods.getConnection = function() {
    return myConn;
}

methods.connectToMongoDb = async function() {
    return MongoClient.connect(url + dbName)
    .then(function(conn) {
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
        myClient = conn;
        myConn = myClient.db(dbName);
        return myConn;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error during connection');
        throw err;
    });
}

methods.closeConnection = async function() {
    myClient.close()
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error closing connection');
        throw err;
    });
}

methods.createACollection = async function(collectionName) {
    return myConn.createCollection(collectionName)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Collection', collectionName, 'created');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error during creation of collection', collectionName);
        throw err;
    });
}

methods.insert = async function(collectionName, obj) {
    return myConn.collection(collectionName).updateOne(obj, {$set: obj}, {upsert: true})
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log('Inserted 1 element in', collectionName);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error during insertion in', collectionName);
        throw err;
    });
}

module.exports = methods;
```

**downloadCoverageIta.js**:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var textract = require('textract');

var util = require('../helpers/util.js');
var mongolib = require('../middlewares/db.js');

var methods = {};

var outDir = './output/';
var finalFilename = outDir + 'coverage-ita.json'

var urls = [
    {year: '2013', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_1_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2012', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_5_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2011', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_6_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2010', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_7_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2009', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_8_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2008', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_15_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2007', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_14_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2006', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_13_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2005', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_12_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2004', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_11_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2003', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_10_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2002', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_9_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2001', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_1_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}, 
    {year: '2000', link: 'http://www.salute.gov.it/imgs/C_17_tavole_20_allegati_iitemAllegati_0_fileAllegati_itemFile_0_file.pdf'}
];

var jsons = [];

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    jsons = await extractText()
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Extract text success');
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log('Extract text error');
    });
}; 

async function extractText() {
    var config = {
        preserveLineBreaks: true
    };

    //await extractTextTest();

    await urls.forEach(async function(url) {
        await textract.fromUrl(url.link, config, async function(error, text) {
            if(error) {
                throw error;
            }
            switch(url.year) {
                case '2000': 
                case '2001': 
                case '2002': 
                case '2003':
                case '2004': 
                case '2005': 
                case '2006': 
                case '2007': 
                case '2008': 
                case '2009': 
                case '2010': 
                case '2011': 
                case '2012':
                    await extractTextType1(url, text)
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('extractTextType1 success');
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        console.log('extractTextType1 error');
                    });
                    break;

                case '2013': 
                    extractTextType2(url, text)
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('extractTextType2 success');
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        console.log('extractTextType2 error');
                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    console.log('Error: no case');
            }
        });
    });
}

async function extractTextTest() { // THIS WORKS
    var obj = {A: 'aa', B: 'bb', C: 'cc'};
    await mongolib.insert('coverages', obj);
}

async function extractTextType1(url, text) {
    var matrix = [];
    var map = [];
    var vaccines = [];
    var regionsTemp = [];
    var regions = [];
    var regionLength = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]; 

    // text to matrix
    var textArray = text.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
        matrix[i] = textArray[i].split(' ');
    }

    matrix[0].shift();
    vaccines = matrix[0];
    map[0] = vaccines;

    for(var i = 0; i < regionLength.length; i++) {
        var j = i + 1; 
        var indexToRemove = 0;
        var numberToRemove = regionLength[i];
        var region = matrix[j].splice(indexToRemove, numberToRemove);
        regionsTemp.push(region);
        map[j+1] = matrix[j];
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < regionsTemp.length; i++) {
        var region = '';
        if(regionLength[i] > 1) {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join(' ');
        }
        else {
            region = regionsTemp[i].join('');
        }
        regions.push(region);
    }
    map[1] = regions;

    vaccines = map.shift(); 
    regions = map.shift(); 

    var thisJson = await map.reduce(function(result, v, i) {
        v.forEach(function(o, k) {
            var obj = util.createJsonObjectCoverage(url.year, 'Italy', vaccines[k], regions[i], o);
            // save on db
            mongolib.insert('coverages', obj); // HERE
            result.push(obj);
        });
        return result;
    }, jsons);

    util.printOnFile(jsons, finalFilename);
}

function extractTextType2(url, text) {
    var matrix = [];
    var map = [];
    var vaccines = [];
    var regions = [];

    var textArray = text.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        matrix[i] = textArray[i].split(' ');
    }

    vaccines.push(matrix[0][1].replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, ''));
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        vaccines.push(matrix[i][0].replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, ''));
    }
    var meningo = ''.concat(matrix[10][0], matrix[11]).replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, '');
    vaccines.push(meningo);
    var pneumo = ''.concat(matrix[12][0], ' ', matrix[13]).replace(/\(a\)/g, '').replace(/\(b\)/g, '').replace(/\(c\)/g, '').replace(/\r/g, '');
    vaccines.push(pneumo);
    map[0] = vaccines;

    for(var i = 14; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
        regions.push(matrix[i][0]);
    }
    map[1] = regions;
    for(var i = 14; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        matrix[i].shift();
        map.push(matrix[i]);
    }

    vaccines = map.shift(); 
    regions = map.shift(); 

    var thisJson = map.reduce(function(result, v, i) {
        v.forEach(function(o, k) {
            var obj = util.createJsonObjectCoverage(url.year, 'Italy', vaccines[k], regions[i], o);
            // save on db
            mongolib.insert('coverages', obj); // HERE
            result.push(obj);
        });
        return result;
    }, jsons);

    util.printOnFile(jsons, finalFilename);
}

module.exports = methods;
```

**downloaderCoverageWho.js**:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var util = require('../helpers/util.js');
var mongolib = require('../middlewares/db.js');

var methods = {};
var countries = {
    'Albania': 'ALB',
    'Austria': 'AUT'
};

var outDir = './output/';
var finalData = outDir + 'coverage-eu.json'
var jsons = [];

methods.download = async function(req, res) {
    for(country in countries) {
        var url = 'http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/coverages?c=' + countries[country];
        request(url, (function(country) {
            var thisCountry = country;

            return function(error, res, html) {
                if(error) {
                    throw error;
                }
                $ = cheerio.load(html);
                var years = [];
                var vaccines = [];
                var coverages = [];
                $('.ts .year').each(function() {
                    years.push($(this).text().trim());
                });
                $('.ts .odd td a, .ts .even td a').each(function() {
                    vaccines.push($(this).text().trim());
                });
                $('.ts .odd .statistics_small, .ts .even .statistics_small').each(function() {
                    coverages.push($(this).text().trim());
                });

                const numYears = years.length;
                const numVaccines = vaccines.length;
                for(var vaccineIdx = 0; vaccineIdx < numVaccines; vaccineIdx++) {
                    for(var yearIdx = 0; yearIdx < numYears; yearIdx++) {
                        let obj = {
                            year: years[yearIdx],
                            country: country,
                            region: "",
                            vaccine: vaccines[vaccineIdx],
                            coverage: coverages[vaccineIdx*numYears + yearIdx]
                        }
                        jsons.push(obj);
                        // save on db
                        mongolib.insert('coverages', obj); // PROBLEM HERE
                    } 
                }
                util.printOnFile(jsons, finalData);
            } 
        })(country)); 
    } 
}; 

module.exports = methods;
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

> (node:11952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection  (rejection id: 2950): MongoError: server instance pool was
>   destroyed

I think there is the same problem in both files (`downloaderCoverageIta` and `downloaderCoverageWho`).

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029893/why-is-the-mongodb-node-driver-generating-instance-pool-destroyed-errors) that probably I'm calling `db.close()` before my `inserts` have completed but this is not true. I don't know how to fix it.

It's the first time I use `async/await`. How can I solve?

Comment: Please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167480/discussion-mongoerror-server-instance-pool-was-destroyed) room

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the issue...

I forgot the fact that javaScript is Async :) 
the mongo.close() was the issue.
I commented it and it worked

Comment: But the point is it has been closed and it has been restarted inside a function. No matter we are destroying it but we are even creating the connection back. Could you please justify what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @Ashish, The fact is I have not understood your question this time. However, as per the subject, you will get "MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed" error only when the mongoDB connection is closed just before querying the mongoDB. The connection object returned by MongoDB is used after closing the connection, so mongoDB rejects the connection object and complains that the object was destroyed already.

Comment: Now, what happens actually is, when you make a successful connection to any database, the db creates a process for your connection (server instance pool) and maintains it until you ask it to destroy or it destroys itself, if it was left open for a long time. So, either of the two events might have occurred in your case. This is just my honest opinion. If this does not answer your question, please re-explain your problem....

Comment: another thing you can do is, to write a console.log in each step and check if your tasks are executed in the order you wish them to execute... :(

Answer (score 3):

I think `db.closeConnection()` is called before all request responses are handled, and database access is finished.

The cause for this behaviour may be, that you are only waiting for creating the requests, but you are not waiting for their result (response).

You start the request with a statement like this inside an async function:

```
request(url, (function(country) {
...
})(...));
```

That means, the async function will wait for the `request(...)` function call, but not for the callback function which handles the response.

You can also use `request(...)` in the following way:

```
const response = await request(url);
```

Now your async function will wait for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server is not able to connect with MongoDB, try restarting the server.

Comment: I have changed mongodb authentication and got this error in nodeJS. Sorting out credentials and restarting apps with pm2 solved it.

Answer (score -2):

"err": "server instance pool was destroyed"

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)

because of this code only u r getting this err...
mark it as comment you will not get this error again...