# MongoDB connection closes after couple of days

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

since I really don't know what the issue might be, I'll just copy-paste the error. I searched Google, but no success so far. The first part of the code is the issue I guess, so I just added the second part in case it might be more helpful. Basically, after a couple of days or so, my DB just stops working and I have no idea why. It's the Cloud Version of MongoDB and I use NodeJs + ExpressJs + Mongoose. Thank you in advance for every hint.

```
0|app      |       at eachAsync (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_mod                                                            ules/mongodb/lib/core/utils.js:135:5)
0|app      |       at Pool.reset (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_mo                                                            dules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:709:3)
0|app      |       at /home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongod                                                            b/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:202:19
0|app      |       at /home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongod                                                            b/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:164:18
0|app      |       at Server.command (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/nod                                                            e_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:239:14)
0|app      |       at checkServer (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_m                                                            odules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:148:12)
0|app      |       at Object.monitorServer [as monitorFunction] (/home/redicerap                                                            /apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:193:3)
0|app      |       at Server.monitor (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/nod                                                            e_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:216:12)
0|app      |       at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backen                                                            d/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:859:22)
0|app      |       at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17) {
0|app      |     name: 'MongoError',
0|app      |     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
0|app      |   },
0|app      |   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
0|app      | }



0|app  | MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
0|app  |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:878:9)
0|app  |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
0|app  |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
0|app  |   name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
0|app  |   reason: MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
0|app  |       at basicWriteValidations (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:408:12)
0|app  |       at basicReadValidations (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:415:17)
0|app  |       at Server.command (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:237:19)
0|app  |       at checkServer (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:148:12)
0|app  |       at /home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:204:7
0|app  |       at /home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:732:9
0|app  |       at eachAsync (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/utils.js:135:5)
0|app  |       at Pool.reset (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:709:3)
0|app  |       at /home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:202:19
0|app  |       at /home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:164:18
0|app  |       at Server.command (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:239:14)
0|app  |       at checkServer (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:148:12)
0|app  |       at Object.monitorServer [as monitorFunction] (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/monitoring.js:193:3)
0|app  |       at Server.monitor (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:216:12)
0|app  |       at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/redicerap/apps/nashinobi/backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:859:22)
0|app  |       at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17) {
0|app  |     name: 'MongoError',
0|app  |     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
0|app  |   },
0|app  |   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
0|app  | }
```

Comment: Check the mongo.close() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429462/mongoerror-server-instance-pool-was-destroyed

Comment: @Girgetto i looked for a solution in this thread already. i don't have a mongo close. i'm just establishing a connection and thats it.

Comment: @AlexG. any solution for this issue? I''m having the same problem with mongodb 4.0.1

Comment: @NimeshaKalinga I'm sorry for this very late response, but the solution was quite simple. I returned a response in 2 different places, because i didn't like the nesting of my mongo queries. so the whole backend crashed because of that, but it was hard to spot because it only happened rarely, but regularly. make sure to return res.status(200) or whatever just ONCE, I made the mistake of thinking that the 2nd return won't be reached at all after the first is triggered.

Comment: @AlexG. Hi Alex, in my case it was something to do with windows updates on the server and the mongodb version. Updated the mongodb to the lastest and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. I returned a response in two different places, because i didn't like the nesting of my Mongoose queries. The whole NodeJS backend crashed because of that, but it was hard to spot because it only happened rarely, but regularly. Make sure to return res.status(200) or whatever just ONCE. I returned a res.status(200) in every Mongoose query that I assigned to a const, thinking that it's ok because the second return won't even be reached, which was the case most of the time. This error is not ralated to mongoose itself.