# MongoError: pool destroyed although I don't run mongo.close()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I got the an "error MongoError: pool destroyed" on my Nodejs code.

"mongoose": "^5.10.8"

'nodejs' : v12.9.1.

I read question: [MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429462/mongoerror-server-instance-pool-was-destroyed)
and got the answer because  mongo.close(). But on my code i don't close any connection to my mongodb docker. What wrong with my code?

Comment: Same issue. Did you fix it ? @Bui Thanh Lam